# Datatable to arrayList object[] = {dtTable.nameColumn = row.value}

Tags: c#, arrays

I need convert DataTable to Array, with column name and value.
like this:

```
string sql = "Select * from tblAlumn;
private DataTable dt = DataBaseHelper.ExecuteQuery(strSQL);
/*I want convert this table to array, :*/
object[] ar = [{nameColumn:value, nameColumn:value,...},
               {nameColumn:value, nameColumn:value,...}, ...]//all Table
```

Comment: Why?  It can be done, but usually it is not necessary.  Leaving as a DataTable has advantages such as having a type which an object doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Below way of invoking worked for me.

dtRecord is your datatable variable

"A", "B", "C" are the column headers.

You can replace "value1", "value2" and "value3" with your name column.

```
var results = dtRecord.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new { value2 = x.Field<string>("A"), value3 = x.Field<string>("B"), value1 = x.Field<string>("C") });
            object[] ar = results.ToArray();
```

After replacing the name columns with respective header names, the query looks as shown below, and the result will be what you expect.

```
var results = dtRecord.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new { A = x.Field<string>("A"), B = x.Field<string>("B"), C = x.Field<string>("B") });
            object[] ar = results.ToArray();
```